# How can we post sitemap to Bing

Tags: seo, liferay, liferay-6

I would like to know how we can post Sitemap to Bing (search engine).

Liferay by default supports for google and yahoo. In addition to that I would also like to add Bing as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a bing webmaster tools account and upload the sitemap. Or put the sitemap as mydomain.com/sitemap.xml and bing will find it automatically. You must use the standard sitemap format:

http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Comment: Thanks for reply..but my requirement is i want to integrate this functionality with Liferay SEO.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "integrate this functionality with Liferay SEO"

Comment: @jonny liferay by default support sitemap for google and yahoo and i want to add one more serch engine like Bing inside it for SEO...hope it clarify.

Comment: The sitemap created by Liferay can be used by Bing as well, they just don't supply the option for your to "ping" it to Bing. However as @Rafael says you can use Bing Webmaster tools to upload the sitemap. Just use the preview link that Liferay gives you, and add that to Bing Webmaster tools.